# Gammu: Error getting SMS status: Security error. Maybe no PIN?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, gammu

I runnng gammu-smsd v. 1.40.0.0-1 on Raspbian 10. I am able to send messages with both sendsms and through gammu-smsd. However, gammu-smsd does not receive messages. When I check my log file /var/log/gammu-smsd.log I see an error below. The modem is a Huawei MS2372. Can anyone advise how I can fix this?

```
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: Leaving GSM_GetSecurityStatus
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: Entering GSM_GetSMSStatus
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: Getting SIM SMS status
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x12/18
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3D=|22"|53S|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|53S|4DM AT+CPMS="SM","SM
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: 22"|0D ".
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: 1 "AT+CPMS="SM","SM""
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: 2 "+CMS ERROR: 302"
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: Checking line: +CMS ERROR: 302
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: AT reply state: 5
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x25/37
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|4DM|53S|3D=|22"|53S|4DM|22"|2C,|22"|53S|4DM AT+CPMS="SM","SM
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: 22"|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM|53S|20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 "...+CMS ERROR:
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: 333|300|322|0D |0A 302..
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: CMS Error 302: "operation not allowed"
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: GSM_GetSMSStatus failed with error SECURITYERROR[23]: Security error. Maybe no PIN?
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: gammu: Leaving GSM_GetSMSStatus
Mon 2020/11/30 16:17:18 gammu-smsd[2761]: Error getting SMS status: Security error. Maybe no PIN? (SECURITYERROR[23])
```